# How to show the "Submit Success" message first then transfer to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to show the "Insert Successful" message in the pop up window first then the page will redirect to the different page. But when I add the Response.Redirect after the java-script, it will jump to next page without showing the message box. Thanks for your help!

```
 try
        {
            connnew.Open();
            cmdnew.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string message = "Form Generated Successfully";
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
            sb.Append("alert('");
            sb.Append(message);
            sb.Append("')};");
            sb.Append("</script>");
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(form1.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());

            Response.Redirect("AllRecords.aspx");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing..

```
Response.Redirect("AllRecords.aspx");
```

you can try this..

```
Response.AddHeader("REFRESH","5;URL=AllRecords.aspx");
```

this will delay the redirect for 5 seconds.

Comment: Works! I just need to change the refresh delay time a little bit shorter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
sb.Append("alert('");
sb.Append(message);
sb.Append("')");
sb.Append("location.replace('AllRecords.aspx');");
sb.Append("};");
```